# Nevron BarChart with DateTimeScaleConfigurator weired series plotting?

Tags: winforms, charts, nevron

I am using Nevron Charting Control ver.11.1.17.12 in application. I am facing problem in drawing the chart correct with the `DateTimeScaleConfigurator`. Here are following problem:

1. Series Bar overlapping each other if series count increases.
2. Series getting out of the Axis lines.
3. X Axis Scale automatically add previous year `December` and next year `Jan` in the scale which cause the chart to have blank area in case of Surface Chart.

*//code snippet to draw Bar Chart Series*

```
NBarSeries bar = new NBarSeries();
bar.UniqueId = new Guid(outputVariable.UniqueId);
bar.Name = outputVariable.LegendText;
chart.Series.Add(bar);
bar.HasBottomEdge = false;
bar.MultiBarMode = chart.Series.Count == 1 ? MultiBarMode.Series : MultiBarMode.Clustered;                   
// bar.InflateMargins = true;
bar.UseZValues = false;

indexOfSeries = chart.Series.IndexOf(bar);
ConfigureChartSeries(bar, indexOfSeries, outputVariable);
SetSeriesAxisInformation(bar, outputVariable.Unit);
bar.UseXValues = true;
foreach (DataRow row in seriesDataTable.Rows)
{
   bar.XValues.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(row["TimeStamp"]).ToOADate());
}
```

*code snippet to Add Surface Chart Series*

```
chart.Enable3D = true;
 chart.BoundsMode = BoundsMode.Stretch;
 (chart as NCartesianChart).Fit3DAxisContent = true;               
 chart.Projection.SetPredefinedProjection(PredefinedProjection.OrthogonalTop);
 chart.LightModel.EnableLighting = false;                   
 chart.Wall(ChartWallType.Back).Visible = false;
 chart.Wall(ChartWallType.Left).Visible = false;
 chart.Wall(ChartWallType.Floor).Visible = false;
 // setup Y axis
 chart.Axis(StandardAxis.PrimaryY).Visible = false;                
 // setup Z axis
 NAxis axisZ = chart.Axis(StandardAxis.Depth);
 axisZ.Anchor = new NDockAxisAnchor(AxisDockZone.TopLeft);
 NLinearScaleConfigurator scaleZ = new NLinearScaleConfigurator();
 scaleZ.InnerMajorTickStyle.Visible = false;
 scaleZ.MajorGridStyle.ShowAtWalls = new ChartWallType[0];
 scaleZ.RoundToTickMin = false;
 scaleZ.RoundToTickMax = false;
 axisZ.ScaleConfigurator = scaleZ;
 axisZ.Visible = true;

 // add a surface series
 NGridSurfaceSeries surface = new NGridSurfaceSeries();
 surface.UniqueId = new Guid(outputVariable.UniqueId);
 surface.Name = outputVariable.LegendText;
 chart.Series.Add(surface);
 surface.Legend.Mode = SeriesLegendMode.SeriesLogic;
 surface.ValueFormatter = new NNumericValueFormatter("0.0");
 surface.FillMode = SurfaceFillMode.Zone;
 surface.FrameMode = SurfaceFrameMode.Contour;
 surface.ShadingMode = ShadingMode.Flat;
 surface.DrawFlat = true;
 // Already set this property to false and working in other chart.
 surface.InflateMargins = false;                    
 surface.FrameColorMode = SurfaceFrameColorMode.Zone;
 surface.SmoothPalette = true;
 surface.Legend.Format = "<zone_value>";
 surface.FillMode = SurfaceFillMode.Zone;
 surface.FrameMode = SurfaceFrameMode.Contour;
 CreateSurfaceSeries(outputVariable, surface);
 chartControl.Refresh();
```

And the ScaleConfigurator configuration

```
chartPrimaryXAxis = chart.Axis(StandardAxis.PrimaryX);
// X Axis Configuration
dateTimeScale = new NDateTimeScaleConfigurator();
dateTimeScale.Title.Text = string.Empty;
dateTimeScale.LabelStyle.Angle = new NScaleLabelAngle(ScaleLabelAngleMode.Scale, 90);
dateTimeScale.LabelStyle.ContentAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
dateTimeScale.LabelStyle.TextStyle.FontStyle = new NFontStyle("Times New Roman", 6);
dateTimeScale.LabelFitModes = new LabelFitMode[] { LabelFitMode.AutoScale };
chartPrimaryXAxis.ScaleConfigurator = dateTimeScale;
chartPrimaryXAxis.ScrollBar.ResetButton.Visible = true;
chartPrimaryXAxis.ScrollBar.ShowSliders = true;
dateTimeScale.EnableUnitSensitiveFormatting = true;
```

Here is the generated output:
[image: Bar Chart Out of Axis Labels]

[image: prevent to show previous and next year in scale]

Any idea regarding this problem will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Series Bar overlapping each other if series count increases.
>
>   &**
>        **Series bar getting out of the Axis lines.**

*Answer:* When you are using categorial data then use `NOrdinalScaleConfigurator` rather than `NDateTimeScaleConfigurator`. It will not solve the problem and put the series bar in the center of the scale and auto resize them according to the chart size also.

> **X Axis Scale automatically add previous year December and next year
>   Jan in the scale which cause the chart to have blank area in case of
>   Surface Chart.**

*Answer:* 
Set the following properties of the `DateTimeScaleConfigurator` to false to avoid such behavior.

```
 dateTimeScale.RoundToTickMax = false;
 dateTimeScale.RoundToTickMin = false;
```